# Chromadb in my local system

Tags: machine-learning, python, gpt

[image: Error Screenshot]

I am trying to install chromadb on my local system but getting following error even after installing Microsoft C++ Build Tools:

Is it because "Chromadb" can only be used in google Collab and there is no way I can use chromadb in my local system? If yes what other libraries can be used to store my vector database locally in my system?

Further information: I am using "langchain" to search the nearest context in my vector database to send that context to OpenAI.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with chromadb, the problem is with a dependency of chromadb called hnswlib. There's apparently a problem with hnswlib on python 3.9 for some people. Please see here: https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib/issues/442 for more details. I just built this on python 3.10.5 with no problems (though it does take several minutes):

```
pip install hnswlib
pip install chromadb
```

You do need to ensure that the Microsoft C++ build tools are in your PATH from the environment you use to build hnswlib. hth.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I check that  Microsoft C++ build tools are in PATH from the environment I use to build hnswlib. hth. or how can I do this?

Comment: If the build tools are in the PATH, you can open a command line and type cl.exe and it will run the compiler. I have Visual Studio 2022 installed, so I hit windows key then type developer command prompt for VS 2022, and it will correctly set up my build environment. Also check this if it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261546/how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-or-greater-is-required-when-inst